# ‘Were reports not taken seriously’ or ‘ Were not reports taken seriously’

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, negation

One of my homework is changing sentences into question sentences. The original sentence is:

> "Reports were not taken seriously."

I am not sure where the ‘not’ should be put.

> ‘Were reports **not** taken seriously’ or ‘Were **not** reports taken seriously’

Which is right? I feel both are right.

Comment: Is there any more context? Why are you asking about these sentences?

Comment: @JamesK The original sentence is : Reports were not taken seriously.   One of my homework is changing this sentence into question sentence. But I am not sure where the ‘not’ should be put.

Comment: Have you done any searching to figure it out? What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: Ok, any easier one: He was not present at the meeting. Transform that into negative interrogative. Verb+subject + not+past participle or adjective.

Comment: @Lambie Okay. I see.

Comment: @gotube My thought is that both negative interrogative are right. Am I fell right?

Answer (score 1):

"Reports were not taken seriously."

Verb: to be

**negative of** to be: am not/is not/are not
Past: was/were

**Reports were not taken seriously.**

**negative interrogative**, inversion

**Were reports not taken seriously?**

Also: **Weren't reports taken seriously?**

Comment: So both are right？

Comment: @Y.zeng The "were not" version is not wrong, exactly, but it's much less likely to be used and sounds off.

Comment: @Casey Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The simple negative question is "Were reports not taken seriously".

The other form "Were not reports taken seriously" is more marked. It has a rhetorical effect as it indicated that the person is expecting the answer "Yes, they were".

Comment: You have the rhetoric reversed. *Am I not beautiful?* expects the answer, *Yes, you are.* The expected answer here should be *Yes, they were.*